# How can I capture a response sent from android to Django server using views.py?

Tags: android, django, json, sqlite, http-post

I am new to the client-server side programming so my question might be basic.

Basically, I am trying to send data in JSON format from android to a Django server. The code for sending the data is the following:

```
      try {
   ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8000/androidweb/edit/");
         JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
         try {
    j.put("name", "cdfe");
   } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", j.toString()));
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
  }catch(Exception e) {
   //catch the exception and print it
 }
```

So my intention is to basically call the url mentioned in code. I added the url to Django urls.py so I can use the views.py class to store the JSON data I entered above in a sqlite database table, which contains only one field called "name". However, I don't know if my approach is right. Most code samples I have seen pass the data to a php file, so I was wondering if it is possible to do it through a python class, views.py?

If it is possible, can you please give me a code sample to be implemented in "views.py" of how to capture JSON data sent from the above code and store it in a table with a "name" field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Data sent via POST is available via `request.POST`. Try examining `request.POST['year']`.

Comment: @Matthew: You're saying that the `setEntity()` call with a `UrlEncodedFormEntity` doesn't set up the POST data properly?

Comment: ok so basically request.POST['year'] captures the json string keyed by "year". Now what's the python code in "views.py" that decomposes the json string so I save the value "cdfe" in the table column named "name" in Django? Should I return a message saying that the saving was successful? Do I even need a php file to do all that work, since most of the blogs I have been reading have a php file that does all this work? Would be great if I can do all the work in python. All I need from Django is to read an write values to the database anyways.

Comment: Use `django.utils.simplejson.loads()` to turn the JSON string into Python objects, then walk them and assign the appropriate element to the attribute of your model.